# Sync two folders using batch file

Tags: batch-file

I want to use a batch file to synchronize 2 folders on Windows, and I'm using the xcopy command like this

```
xcopy /s /d <Original Folder> <Destination Folder>
```

It's working perfectly because I just want to overwrite only the modified ones, but I have 1 tiny problem, when I delete a file from the original folder, that file remains in the destination folder when i run the batch file, breaking the synching I want to achieve... I think this can't be done with xcopy, but I don't know which command I should use in case I delete a file in the original folder.

EDIT: This programs is for people who don't understant a lot of PC's so i don't want to install anything in their pc's. Just want a plain batch file to keep the 2 folders synchronized

SOLUTION: Thanks to Kuba Wyrostek I got to this command

robocopy <Original Folder> <Destination Folder> /e /purge

Thank you all for your time

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`xcopy` has no such option. Your alternatives are:

rsync - http://rsync.samba.org

robocopy - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145.aspx

Answer (score 21):

To refine your answer, you can simply do:
`robocopy <Original Folder> <Destination Folder> /mir`

`/mir` mirrors a directory tree (equivalent to `/e` plus `/purge`).

Answer (score 2):

The XCOPY command for copying the updates from one folder to another is as follows:

```
C:\> XCOPY C:/SOURCE D:/DESTINATION /E /D /C /Y
```

The flags used in the above example have the following meanings:

- `/E` causes all folders and sub-folders to be copied
- `/D` causes a DATE comparison to be made, only copying items that are newer than the DESTINATION item. If the DESTINATION is older, or does not contain the file, then it will be copied.
- `/C` tells XCOPY to continue if it encounters an error - typically errors occur with read-only files, or files that have protected permissions
- `/Y` tells XCOPY to suppress prompting you for confirmation, which is necessary if you intend to create an automation script or scheduled task

Comment: This does not answer the original question.

Comment: @geisterfurz007 Are you sure this is not the original?  That article doesn't have a date, but its oldest disqus comment is 10 months *after* this post.  If you believe a post is plagiarized, please raise a moderator flag.

Comment: @RyanBemrose Argh what have I done >.> Nifty little detail and an idea I did not even think about. Took away my comment and downvote. Thanks for the note and hint for potential future cases :)

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old,  but I have a question.  Can this not be done with the correct xcopy commands.

Folder 1:  c:\workingFolder\"contents here"

Folder 2:  d:\workingFolderSync\"contents here"

Batch file below

```
xcopy "c:\workingFolder\*.*" "d:\workingFolderSync\" /i /s /d /y
xcopy "d:\workingFolderSync\*.*" "c:\workingFolder\" /i /s /d /y
pause
```

(  I usually remove the **pause** after i test and know the batch works. )
But this will only copy contents from the folder to the other if its newer.
Then it looks in the destination folder and copies contents from destination back to source if it is newer.  This reproduces what syncing does, except for the in real time monitoring of modified files.  Creating a proper task schedule can actually implement running this command at specific times to almost perfectly reproduce syncing.  You can also run this before modification on a machine and after modification on a machine.  Even doing the same thing on a second machine if your using a network drive to sync.

Answer (score 0):

Your method will have two main problems:

- Files deleted from one folder will be reinstated by the copy left in the other folder the next time you run your xcopy
- Renaming files can cause chaotic results.

Comment: How is this an answer?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest make use of robocopy, the copy resumes if there is a disconnection in the network. And it is faster than xcopy.

Save the below lines in a bat or cmd file so that you can schedule its run

```
set source=<Original Folder>
set target=<Destination Folder>

robocopy /mir %source% %target%
```